# Elasticsearch Query String with Dot/Point at the end, i.e. +foo.*

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have an index containing lot's of streets. The index looks like this:

```
Mainstreet 42
Some other street 15
Foostr. 9
```

The default search query looks like this:

```
+QUERY_STRING*
```

So querying for `foo` (sent as `+foo*`) or `foostr` (sent as `+foostr*`) results in `Foostr. 9`, which is correct. **BUT** querying for `foostr.` (which get's sent to Elasticsearch as `+foostr.*`) gives no results, but why?

I use standard analyzer and the query string with no special options. (This also returns 0 results when using `http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/streets?q=+foostr.*`).

Btw. this: `http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/streets?q=+foostr.` (same as above without the asterisk) finds the right results

### Questions:

1. Why is this happening?
2. How to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing i didn't think about was:

*Elasticsearch will **not** analyze wildcard queries by default!*

This means. By **default** it will act like this:

```
input query | the query that ES will use
----------------------------------------
foo         | foo
foo.        | foo
foo*        | foo*
foo.*       | foo.*
```

As you can see, if the input query contains a wildcard, ES will not remove any characters. When using no wildcard, ES will take the query and run an analyzer, which (i.e. when using the default analyzer) will remove all dots.

To "fix" this, you can either

- Remove all dots manually from the query string. Or
- Use `analyze_wildcard=true` (i.e. `http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/streets?q=+foostr.*&analyze_wildcard=true`). Here's an explanation of what happens: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/787

Answer (score 0):

1) This is because standard analyser does not index special characters. Example if you index a string `Yoo! My name is Karthik.`, elasticsearch breaks it down to `(yoo, my, name, is, karthik)` without special characters (which actually makes sense in many simple cases) and in lowercase. So, when you search for `foostr.`, there were no results.. as it was indexed as `foostr` (without ".").

2) You can use different types of analysers for different fields depending on your requirement while indexing (or you can use no_analyser as well).

Example:-

```
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/bookstore/book/_mapping' -d '
{
    "book" : {
        "properties" : {
            "title" : {"type" : "string", "analyzer" : "simple"},
            "description" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
        }
    }
}
'
```

You can refer [this](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) and [this](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html) for more information.

HTH!

Comment: I thought ES will also analyze my query string, so my search query will loose its dot.

Comment: I edited the question. So querying for `+foostr.` works, but `+foostr.*` doesn't. Maybe you could explain this, too? Thank you.